# IBQuery insert - Column unknown / Unsupported feature

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, auto-increment, interbase

Im trying to insert a row into a firebird database (embedded), but geting an exception when calling:

```
datamodule1.IBQuery1.prepare
```

> Project xyz.exe raised  exception class EIBInterBaseError with message
>   'Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown INDEX_ At
>   line,  column 25'.

```
  with datamodule1.IBQuery1 do
  begin
    close; 
    With SQL do
    begin
      clear; 
      Add( 'INSERT INTO MST_EVENTS (eventindex, state_, event_, param_, date_, time_, devID_, gateway_)' );
      Add( 'VALUES (:eventindex, :state_, :event_, :param_, :date_, :time_, :devid_, :gateway_') );
    end;
    //
    GeneratorField.Field := 'Nr_';
    GeneratorField.Generator := 'GEN_MST_EVENTS_ID';
    //
    Params[0].AsInteger := FMst.EventRecordIndex; 
    Params[1].AsSmallInt := FMst.EventRecordState; 
    Params[2].AsString := eventToStr(FMst.EventRecordEvent);          
    Params[3].AsSmallInt := 0;
    Params[4].AsDate := FMst.EventRecordDate; 
    Params[5].AsTime := FMst.EventRecordTime; 
    Params[6].AsLongWord := FMst.EventRecordDevID; 
    Params[7].AsString := FMst.EventRecordIP; 
    //
    if ( prepared = false ) then
      prepare;  //Throws an exception here (SOLVED)
    execSQL;    //Now getting exception here 
  end;
```

I have the following components tied together:

- IBDatabase
- IBTransaction
- DataSource
- IBQuery

**Above problem solved - Edit >>** 
Ok, i have changed

```
Add( 'INSERT INTO MST_EVENTS (eventindex, state_, event_, param_, date_, time_, devID_, gateway_)' );
```

to

```
Add( 'INSERT INTO MST_EVENTS ("eventindex", "state_", "event_", "param_", "date_", "time_", "devID_", "gateway_")' );
```

... (so im using quotation marks) and now it finds the fields, but get another exception at line:

```
 IBQuery1.execSQL:
```

> *Exception class EIBClientError with message 'Unsupported feature'*

My fields are:

```
Nr_        : INTEGER
eventindex : INTEGER
state_     : SMALLINT
event_     : VARCHAR(50)
param_     : SMALLINT
date_      : DATE
time_      : TIME
devID_     : BIGINT
gateway_   : VARCHAR(50)
```

Firebird version is 2.5 embedded 32bit

I took out all the string and date/time parameters, yet i get the exception.
Using IBExpert and the same client/server .dll i can insert the row flawlessly (using all the values).

Comment: Slow down. Make sure you have all the column changes committed and that all your column names matches to those listed in the query. Using quotes should work. What is mismatched are the names of `devID_` and `gateway_` column names. But hard to say *which version* have you posted here.

Comment: @Tlama sorry, i modified the code i pasted here, but the first part of the problem was already solved, now faced with another exception...

Comment: `... values ( ... )` - add brackets to the query text

Comment: @Abelisto sorry, yes its just another thing i left out from the pasted code, but in the code editor its ok, so thats not the problem.

Comment: I edited my question so hopefully there are no more mistakes.

Comment: The error _EIBClientError with message 'Unsupported feature'_ (and the distinction between client and server with `EIBInterBaseError`) seems to indicate you are using a feature not implemented in the component.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel now im 'only' getting the 'Unsupported feature' exception, but i left the topic name as it is, because it can help finding solution for others, related to my first problem.

Comment: @tdiop I understand, but I want to indicate that the problem is most likely client side not server side. But as I don't know Delphi nor the component I can't offer further insights). I can suggest to try to simplify (eg leave out the `GeneratorField`, try without parameters, etc) and to check the documentation of the component

Comment: Another hint: Call `prepare` before you set parameters values or do not call it at all.

Comment: _Unsupported feature_ can often be related to the driver you're using.  Verify that you're using fbclient.dll found in the syswow64 folder if you're using 64 bit server and 32bit client.  It's possible that your connection is using gds32.dll which may/may not be the problem.

Comment: Just to make a test try to insert `Nr_` value explicitly without using a generator and see what will happen.

Comment: @Jason the fact that before (with unquoted columns) he got an error from the server seems to indicate that the driver is loaded correctly and working.

Comment: I tried everything you guys came up with (thank you!), but no luck. Btw im using fb 2.5 embedded 32bit (tried x64 version also but with that i cannot even connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was changing line

```
Params[6].AsLongWord := FMst.EventRecordDevID;
```

to

```
Params[6].AsLargeInt := FMst.EventRecordDevID;
```

But please how to auto-increment the field 'Nr_'?

```
  with datamodule1.IBQuery1 do
  begin
    close; 
    With SQL do
    begin
      clear; 
      Add( 'INSERT INTO MST_EVENTS (eventindex, state_, event_, param_, date_, time_, devID_, gateway_)' );
      Add( 'VALUES (:eventindex, :state_, :event_, :param_, :date_, :time_, :devid_, :gateway_') );
    end;
    //
    GeneratorField.Field := 'Nr_';
    GeneratorField.Generator := 'GEN_MST_EVENTS_ID';
    //
    Params[0].AsInteger := FMst.EventRecordIndex; 
    Params[1].AsSmallInt := FMst.EventRecordState; 
    Params[2].AsString := eventToStr(FMst.EventRecordEvent);          
    Params[3].AsSmallInt := 0;
    Params[4].AsDate := FMst.EventRecordDate; 
    Params[5].AsTime := FMst.EventRecordTime; 
    Params[6].AsLargeInt := FMst.EventRecordDevID; 
    Params[7].AsString := FMst.EventRecordIP; 
    //
    if ( prepared = false ) then
      prepare;  //Throws an exception here (SOLVED)
    execSQL;    //Now getting exception here 
  end;
```

I made the generator in flamerobin.
[image]

But getting exception (at calling 'execSQL'): 
[image: Validation error]

**EDIT >>**

I set up a generator and a BEFORE INSERT trigger in IBExpert:

[image]
[image]

And now its ok.

Comment: You really shouldn't ask (and then answer) another question in an answer. I suggest that you post another question and answer it yourself, and then remove that part from this answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes you are right, but please just let me leave this here as it is. I completed my question with the 'auto-increment' tag, so someone can find the answer for that question too. Next time i will be more consistent.